# face grab not working as expected?

Tags: modeling, mesh, sculpting, faces

Hey there I'm new to blender and am simply trying to grab a face on my object and move it down, thus lowering the rest of the objects faces as well, its hard to explain but here are a couple pictures, before:[image]

and after:[image]

so why is it just making a new edge half way down the cube instead of shrinking said cube? I'm selecting the top face, grabbing and moving it down the Z axis to produce this result. Dont know if it matters but also this cube is a duplicate of the one behind it with no addons/modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

You must have some overlapping geometry.

First, select all with <kbd>A</kbd> and then press <kbd>M</kbd> and select *Merge by Distance* to remove any doubled vertices.  Then you should only have one available top face to move.

If the cube was duplicated from another object, that one probably has the same situation.